# How long does it take for Google Maps to include a newly opened highway in its driving directions?

Tags: online-resources, driving, maps

The last section of Autoroute 30 in Quebec opened on December 15, 2012, from Chateauguay to Vaudreuil-Dorion, completing the southern bypass around Montreal, and including a new bridge over the St. Lawrence River; see [here](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/story/2012/12/15/montreal-quebec-highway-30-opens.html), [here](http://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/mediaroom/releases-2012-h135e-6998.htm), and [here](http://www.autoroute30.qc.ca/en/nouvelles-detail.asp?Id=161).  Google Maps shows the new highway on the map, but does not yet include it in driving directions.  For example, a trip from Beauharnois to Les Cedres should be about 17 km using the new highway 30, but Google still gives a 40-km route, crossing the river much farther west using Route 201.

How long does it usually take for Google to update its driving directions, and what can we do to help?

Comment: I am not certain whether this is a travel question. But I don't know if [webapps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) SE or [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) SE would be better places for it. Anyway, this is a nice question and I am waiting for answers.

Comment: I agree with @mouviciel, the question doesn't seem to fit in this Q&A site. Maybe there is a better one.

Comment: I think [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com/) is probably the best place. It all depends on what country it's in, and hence what deals (if any) they have with the national mapping agency and how pro-active that agency is. In the mean time, try [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) - they tend to be very good at adding new roads, and if they miss one you can fix it yourself!

Comment: I would've said webapps.SE because I've asked Google Maps questions there before (at least I think I have) whereas I'm not really familiar with GIS.

Comment: I've have had opposite problem, Google Maps included directions for newly constructed highway, which wasn't opened yet...

Comment: If Google Maps isn't always accurate enough, I heave Apple have made their own maps application to replace it on their smartphones and tablets.

Comment: @Gagravarr How do you get driving directions on OpenStreetMap?

Comment: [OpenRouteService](http://openrouteservice.org/) is the most common one to use, but because the data is open there are several available (both online and off)

Comment: If you want to see up to date maps, you could try openstreetmap, a wiki base map.

Answer (score 7):

Google has a tool called Mapmaker http://www.google.com/mapmaker which you can edit Google Maps and then submit for approval. I used it in the past it took me three days to get the approval. And only 2 days before it went live.

The tool it's a community-based so real people will actually go and see if the change is correct. I guess 5 days for me is pretty decent.

Comment: It's only available in a small number of countries though, so depending on where you are you might well not be able to use it

Comment: When I was living in Georgia I had some edits go live quite quickly, and others seemingly stuck in their old ways for ages. I mainly corrected locations of hostels but started checking or adding street names in various languages and adding and removing landmarks too for a while.

Comment: Here is a list of the countries where mapmaker works by the way: http://support.google.com/mapmaker/answer/155415?topic=1094318&hl=en

Comment: The highway is already shown on the map; the problem is that it isn't being used in the driving directions.

Comment: Okay, I see that Mapmaker now does use the new highway in its driving directions, but Google Maps doesn't.  Does that mean the addition should be making its way to Google Maps soon?

Comment: I believe that'd be updated to Google Maps as well.

Comment: It would be worth updating this answer now that Google Mapmaker has been integrated into the main Google Maps platform.